# AttributeError: module 'pytesseract.pytesseract' has no attribute 'pytesseract'. Did you mean: 'run_tesseract'?

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

This is the code:

```py
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
im = Image.open(r"screenshot.png")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
print(text)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mark\Documents\Scripts\screenshot.py", line 3, in <module>
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
AttributeError: module 'pytesseract.pytesseract' has no attribute 'pytesseract'. Did you mean: 'run_tesseract'?
```

I've done almost everything that's recommended here: installing Tesseract-OCR, adding it to the environment variables, pip install, etc...

what am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you change `from pytesseract import pytesseract` to `import pytesseract`? It sounds like an error to do with how you are calling functions from that library.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pytesseract import pytesseract
```

This import statement means that there is a module named `pytesseract.pytesseract`, and as a convenience, you're calling it simply `pytesseract`.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '...'
```

In order for that line of code to work, there would have to be a module named `pytesseract.pytesseract.pytesseract`, which seems doubtful.

Comment: That did it. Now I get an error at line 5: Error opening data file ?C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.') 

I do have TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable set to tessdata directory. And I did check the English language box when installing it